# Fold code in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

Having previously used TeXstudio, I used the `% BEGIN_FOLD` command to fold sections of code manually in the code representation, e.g. for loading packages etc. (see below). Now switching to Overleaf, I couldn't figure out how to do this - is there a way to achieve this? (I know it is possible for `\begin{section}` etc. but I would like to achieve the same result for manually defined chunks (the `% BEGIN_FOLD` and `% END_FOLD` section in below code). Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

% BEGIN_FOLD -----------PACKAGES------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% END_FOLD -----------PACKAGES------------

\begin{document}
    \section{First section}
        \paragraph{}
            \lipsum[1]
    
    \section{Second section}
        \paragraph{}
            \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf Helpdesk? I hear the Fu of their LaTeX specialists is strong.

Comment: Hi Ivo! Tom from Overleaf Support here. We don't have the ability to specify manual code-folding places. I have raised this to our Product team for consideration. Thanks for writing in!

If you want it for the preamble, you can move everything in the preamble into a separate file (e.g. `preamble.tex`) and then just do `\input{preamble}`. Just please always keep `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` in the main file (do not move these two into the preamble) or the Overleaf compiler would get confused.

Answer (score 13):

You can fold on overleaf using `% {` and `% }`. I like it because you can organize a big text and it won't affect your file at all.

```
% FORMAT AND PACKAGES
% {
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=20mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% }

% DOCUMENT
% {
\begin{document}
\title{RADA RADA RADA}
This text will be folded without cursing your file
% }

% SECTIONS
% {
\section*{BLABLABLA}
blablabla
% }

\end{document}
```

You can see how it works on the pictures below :D

[image] [image]

Comment: Click in the margin at the right of the line numbers to fold lines

Comment: It also works with most structures \begin{envt} ... \end{envt} : you have a dot to click on to fold. What a nice improvement !

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but, as a workaround, I am for now using the way described [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project#Preamble_in_a_separate_file), using a separate file starting with `\ProvidesPackage{costumname}` which is saved as `costumname.sty` and used in the main document with `\usepackage{costumname}`.